# How to make statistics cookies count any TODO entries in the subtree for the whole document?

Tags: org-mode

By default statistics cookies count the number of TODO in the immediate children, not in the full subtree. E.g.

```
* Test [0/0]
** Task1
*** TODO Subtask 1
*** TODO Subtask 2
```

It is [possible](http://orgmode.org/manual/Breaking-down-tasks.html) to change this behavior for a single tree:

```
* Test [0/2]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :COOKIE_DATA: recursive
  :END:
** Task1
*** TODO Subtask 1
*** TODO Subtask 2
```

Or for globally for all the documents:

```
(setq org-hierarchical-todo-statistics nil)
```

Is there a way to set this this on per-document basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [file-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html). This way you can set `org-hierarchical-todo-statistics` (or other variables) on a per-file basis.